# Change the background color when the conditions are met on the input

Tags: javascript, html

How to make the previous second input change color, the previous input only shows numbers and the next input follows ?

like this:

[image: Input]

this is the code i tried :

```js
 let digitValidate = function (ele) {
        ele.style.backgroundColor = "#0f6a19";
        ele.style.color = "#0f6a19";
        if (ele.value === '') {
            ele.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
            ele.style.color = "#005E6A";
        }
        ele.value = ele.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    }

    let tabChange = function (val) {
        let ele = document.querySelectorAll('#input');
        if (ele[val - 1].value !== '') {
            ele[val].focus();
        } else if (ele[val - 1].value === '') {
            ele[val - 2].focus();
        }
    }
```

```css
form input {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
 }

 .otp {
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-color: #005E6A;
 }
```

```html
<form action="" class="mt-4">
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(1)' maxlength=1>
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(2)' maxlength=1>
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(3)' maxlength=1>
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(4)' maxlength=1>
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(5)' maxlength=1>
  <input id="input" class="otp" type="text" oninput='digitValidate(this)' onkeyup='tabChange(6)' maxlength=1>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Please add the details of your requirement to avoid cloosing of the question.

Comment: @AbinThaha when the focus is on the third box and the previous two boxes are filled. Then the two previous boxes will change color and the previous box will display numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of input type as text, you can specify it to be number and give it min and max values.  You can use css to style so that blank input style is different from the filled ones.  You cannot use the same Id for all inputs.  So instead of Id use class to select all input boxes.

```
        <form action="" class="mt-4">
            <input  class="otp" type="number" onkeyup='tabChange(1)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
            <input  class="otp" type="number"  onkeyup='tabChange(2)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
            <input  class="otp" type="number"  onkeyup='tabChange(3)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
            <input  class="otp" type="number"  onkeyup='tabChange(4)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
            <input  class="otp" type="number"  onkeyup='tabChange(5)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
            <input  class="otp" type="number"  onkeyup='tabChange(6)' placeholder=" " min="0" max="9">
        </form>

input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background-color: green;
  color:black;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}

let tabChange = function (val) {
    let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.otp');
    if (ele[val - 1].value !== '') {
        ele[val].focus();
    } else if (ele[val - 1].value === '') {
        ele[val - 1].focus();
    }
}
```